# Javascript Radix Sort

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting

I have been looking around the web for a while and I am wondering if there is a 'stable' defacto implementation of Radix Sort that is generally used?

Two classifications of radix sorts are least significant digit (LSD) radix sorts and most significant digit (MSD) radix sorts.

Looking for an example of LSD or MSD.

Comment: This is off topic here. Please visit the [help] to see why. It is likely a better match at CODEREVIEW

Comment: Just updated the question, thanks

Comment: The standard way to implement radix sort is LSD. It's been this way since the days of card sorters in the 1950's. With LSD, after each radix sort step, the bins can be concatenated for the next step. With MSD, the bins have to be kept separated, so if sorting base 10, that 10 bins on the first step, 100 bins on the second step, 1000 bins on the third step, ... , so it's not normally used.

Comment: Radix Sort is a unique and interesting sorting algorithm, because it sorts arrays without making any comparisons between elements. Therefore if you are comparing you are not writing a radix sort.

How is that even possible? It works on numbers, not strings, aka you can sort [11, 423, 3] bc you can still count how many digits are in the number. 11 is bigger than 3 bc it has two digits vs one. No comparison of the actual numbers, just how many significant digits.

Comment: If someone can write a radix sort in javascript cleanly and with far fewer loops please let me know with @jasonleonhard I am still curious what that would look like. My guess would be a single loop with conditionals instead of extra loops, but I have not seen an implementation with less than 3 loops yet as of today, regardless if the loops are in separate methods or not. Thank you everyone for your input in advance!

Comment: @jasonleonhard: The number of loops is a very poor estimate for performance.  While number of runtime *nested* loops might tell a bit more, the bounds of those loops will be what determines the speed.  Have you benchmarked the various solutions before criticizing their number of loops?

Comment: @ScottSauyet Loops increase how long the program takes to complete, especially when you have loops inside of other loops "nested loops", which can cause the running time to increase exponentially. Avoiding loops inside loops where the number of iterations are dependent the inputs, will execute your program faster in the worst case situations. There’s usually a better way to do it if you step back. Excessive nested loops are a "Code Smell" and if possible it would be best to refactor some of these answers to minimize them. It's fine to start with them, just then improve them.

Comment: I genuinely care about code performance and have been seeking personal improvement in this area, which is why I stumbled across this question and answers. I am asking: Can we improve any of these answers by minimizing loop usage, in particular nested loops, but also any other computationally expensive operations, while still keeping the code clean as possible? Why? Sorting is very important and what other valid reason is there to use a sort method like radix than to improve performance? If not better than alternatives use the alternatives right?

Comment: Also, separately, I would also remind us the OP asked: "I am wondering if there is a 'stable' defacto implementation of Radix Sort that is generally used?" Not can everyone implement radix and see if it's good enough.... though that might be all the answers we receive here and sure they might be good enough, I suspect the OP and many others would like the most efficient radix sort that is cleanly implemented. It sounds like a good goal at least to me. No personal attacks, just seeing an area that could be improved and wanted to see if anyone cared to take a crack at it. Thank you, best wishes!

Comment: For more on this take a peek at these: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/213917/157083
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/213932/157083

Comment: @jasonleonhard: The first question when you're considering performance, though, should be *Have you run a benchmark*?  Until you have real data, it's hard to take the question seriously.  The second question might be to ask about algorithmic complexity, but I think nearly all the solutions here (including the one I added a few hours ago) are in the same time complexity class.  Note that it is impossible to do a radix sort with fewer than two nested loops or loop-equivalents, and some loops, like ones to create 10 buckets, are irrelevant. You might try https://jsbench.me/ to start.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My version is more verbose, but executes quickly even for large number of items:

```
  var testArray = [ 331, 454, 230, 34, 343, 45, 59, 453, 345, 231, 9 ];

  function radixBucketSort (arr) {
    var idx1, idx2, idx3, len1, len2, radix, radixKey;
    var radices = {}, buckets = {}, num, curr;
    var currLen, radixStr, currBucket;

    len1 = arr.length;
    len2 = 10;  // radix sort uses ten buckets

    // find the relevant radices to process for efficiency        
    for (idx1 = 0;idx1 < len1;idx1++) {
      radices[arr[idx1].toString().length] = 0;
    }
    
    // loop for each radix. For each radix we put all the items
    // in buckets, and then pull them out of the buckets.
    for (radix in radices) {          
      // put each array item in a bucket based on its radix value
      len1 = arr.length;
      for (idx1 = 0;idx1 < len1;idx1++) {
        curr = arr[idx1];
        // item length is used to find its current radix value
        currLen = curr.toString().length;
        // only put the item in a radix bucket if the item
        // key is as long as the radix
        if (currLen >= radix) {
          // radix starts from beginning of key, so need to
          // adjust to get redix values from start of stringified key
          radixKey = curr.toString()[currLen - radix];
          // create the bucket if it does not already exist
          if (!buckets.hasOwnProperty(radixKey)) {
            buckets[radixKey] = [];
          }
          // put the array value in the bucket
          buckets[radixKey].push(curr);          
        } else {
          if (!buckets.hasOwnProperty('0')) {
            buckets['0'] = [];
          }
          buckets['0'].push(curr);          
        }
      }
      // for current radix, items are in buckets, now put them
      // back in the array based on their buckets
      // this index moves us through the array as we insert items
      idx1 = 0;
      // go through all the buckets
      for (idx2 = 0;idx2 < len2;idx2++) {
        // only process buckets with items
        if (buckets[idx2] != null) {
          currBucket = buckets[idx2];
          // insert all bucket items into array
          len1 = currBucket.length;
          for (idx3 = 0;idx3 < len1;idx3++) {
            arr[idx1++] = currBucket[idx3];
          }
        }
      }
      buckets = {};
    }
  }
  radixBucketSort(testArray);
  console.log(testArray);
```

Comment: You are using a lot of loops here (5) and thus this will not be a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 5):

The following function does LSB radix sort on Uint32 values. It is faster than the built-in sort function, by the way.

It uses typed arrays to improve performance, but works just as fine if you pass plain arrays, as long as they contain only 32 bit values:

```
function radixSortUint32(input) {
  const arrayConstr = input.length < (1 << 16) ?
    Uint16Array :
    Uint32Array;
  const numberOfBins = 256 * 4;
  let count = new arrayConstr(numberOfBins);

  let output = new Uint32Array(input.length);

  // count all bytes in one pass
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let val = input[i];
    count[val & 0xFF]++;
    count[((val >> 8) & 0xFF) + 256]++;
    count[((val >> 16) & 0xFF) + 512]++;
    count[((val >> 24) & 0xFF) + 768]++;
  }

  // create summed array
  for (let j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
    let t = 0,
      sum = 0,
      offset = j * 256;
    for (let i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
      t = count[i + offset];
      count[i + offset] = sum;
      sum += t;
    }
  }

  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let val = input[i];
    output[count[val & 0xFF]++] = val;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let val = output[i];
    input[count[((val >> 8) & 0xFF) + 256]++] = val;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let val = input[i];
    output[count[((val >> 16) & 0xFF) + 512]++] = val;
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    let val = output[i];
    input[count[((val >> 24) & 0xFF) + 768]++] = val;
  }

  return input;
}
```

Here's how you re-use the above for `Int32` values:

```
function radixSortInt32(input) {
  // make use of ArrayBuffer to "reinterpret cast"
  // the Int32Array as a Uint32Array
  let uinput = input.buffer ?
    new Uint32Array(input.buffer):
    Uint32Array.from(input);

  // adjust to positive nrs
  for (let i = 0; i < uinput.length; i++) {
    uinput[i] += 0x80000000;
  }

  // re-use radixSortUint32
  radixSortUint32(uinput);

  // adjust back to signed nrs
  for (let i = 0; i < uinput.length; i++) {
    uinput[i] -= 0x80000000;
  }

  // for plain arrays, fake in-place behaviour
  if (input.buffer === undefined){
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
      input[i] = uinput[i];
    }
  }

  return input;
}
```

And a similar trick for `Float32` values:

```
function radixSortFloat32(input) {
  // make use of ArrayBuffer to "reinterpret cast"
  // the Float32Array as a Uint32Array
  let uinput = input.buffer ?
    new Uint32Array(input.buffer) :
    new Uint32Array(Float32Array.from(input).buffer);

  // Similar to radixSortInt32, but uses a more complicated trick
  // See: http://stereopsis.com/radixSort.html
  for (let i = 0; i < uinput.length; i++) {
    if (uinput[i] & 0x80000000) {
      uinput[i] ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    } else {
      uinput[i] ^= 0x80000000;
    }
  }

  // re-use radixSortUint32
  radixSortUint32(uinput);

  // adjust back to original floating point nrs
  for (let i = 0; i < uinput.length; i++) {
    if (uinput[i] & 0x80000000) {
      uinput[i] ^= 0x80000000;
    } else {
      uinput[i] ^= 0xFFFFFFFF;
    }
  }

  if (input.buffer === undefined){
    let floatTemp = new Float32Array(uinput.buffer);
    for(let i = 0; i < input.length; i++){
      input[i] = floatTemp[i];
    }
  }

  return input;
}
```

I made a set of these functions that work with all TypedArrays that are 32 bits or less. That is:

- Uint32Array
- Int32Array
- Float32Array
- Uint16Array
- Int16Array
- Uint8Array
- Int8Array
- Any plain array where you know all values fit one of these criteria

[Full gist here](https://gist.github.com/JobLeonard/eb482c82dfa0a5b78688109652ab8f68). I might have a go at Float64 later, then we would have support for *all* javascript numbers, basically.

[TypedArray benchmarks shows radix beats the built-in sort function](https://run.perf.zone/view/Radix-sorts-for-typed-arrays-v2-1507847259416).

[It's faster with plain arrays too, although not quite as much because of the added overhead](https://run.perf.zone/view/Radix-sort-32-bit-int-with-plain-array-test-1507850042653)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript LSD sort:

```
var counter = [[]];
function sortLSD(array, maxDigitSymbols) {
    var mod = 10;
    var dev = 1;
    for (var i = 0; i < maxDigitSymbols; i++, dev *= 10, mod *= 10) {
        for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
            var bucket = parseInt((array[j] % mod) / dev);
            if (counter[bucket] == null ) {
                counter[bucket] = [];
            }
            counter[bucket].push(array[j]);
        }
        var pos = 0;
        for (var j = 0; j < counter.length; j++) {
            var value = null ;
            if (counter[j] != null ) {
                while ((value = counter[j].shift()) != null ) {
                    array[pos++] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
var test = [22, 1,2,9,3,2,5,14,66];
console.log(sortLSD(test, 2));
```

Comment: Concise and legible answer is +1 but you are using a lot of loops here (4) and thus this will not be a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 1):

With below code you can pass array with large number of items.

```js
var counter = [
  []
]; // Radix sort Array container to hold arrays from 0th digit to 9th digits

function radixSortLSD(array) {
  var max = 0,
    mod = 10,
    dev = 1; //max
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > max) {
      max = array[i];
    }
  }
  // determine the large item length
  var maxDigitLength = (max + '').length;
  for (var i = 0; i < maxDigitLength; i++, dev *= 10, mod *= 10) {
    for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
      var bucket = Math.floor((array[j] % mod) / dev); // Formula to get the significant digit
      if (counter[bucket] == undefined) {
        counter[bucket] = [];
      }
      counter[bucket].push(array[j]);
    }
    var pos = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < counter.length; j++) {
      var value = undefined;
      if (counter[j] != undefined) {
        while ((value = counter[j].shift()) != undefined) {
          array[pos++] = value;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("ARRAY: " + array);
};

var sampleArray = [1, 121, 99553435535353534, 345, 0];
radixSortLSD(sampleArray);
```

Answer (score 1):

## Radix Sort (LSD)

```
function radixSort(arr) {
  const base = 10;
  let divider = 1;
  let maxVal = Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY;

  while (divider === 1 || divider <= maxVal) {
    const buckets = [...Array(10)].map(() => []);

    for (let val of arr) {
      buckets[Math.floor((val / divider) % base)].push(val);
      maxVal = val > maxVal ? val : maxVal;
    }

    arr = [].concat(...buckets);
    divider *= base;
  }

  return arr;
}
```

*Disclaimer: it works only with positive integers.*

- For mixed negative & positive integers check [this](https://jsfiddle.net/liormb/rn31a2p6/1/) version.
- I avoid using `Math.max` as it uses a lot of resources for very large arrays.

Comment: Concise and legible answer is +1 but you are using a lot of loops here (3) and thus this will not be a very efficient solution.

Comment: With that said, at the time of writing this, this answer is both the most concise and the least amount of loops (3) a tie with @Abanoub Fathy on the n loops but more concise and all handled in one method (which has its own pros and cons).

Answer (score 1):

Doing a LSD radix sort via bitwise operations could go something like this:

```js
const initialMask = 0b1111;
const bits = 4;

const getBuckets = () => Array.from(
  { length: (2 * initialMask) + 1 },
  () => [],
);

function radixSort(array) {
  let max = 0;
  array.forEach(n => {
    const abs = Math.abs(n);
    if (abs > max) max = abs;
  });

  if (max >= 0x80000000) {
    throw new Error('cannot perform bitwise operations on numbers >= 0x80000000');
  }

  for (
    let mask = initialMask,
      shifted = 0,
      buckets = getBuckets();
    true;
    mask = (mask << bits),
      shifted = (shifted + bits),
      buckets = getBuckets()
  ) {
    array.forEach(n => {
      const digit = mask & Math.abs(n);
      const bucket = (Math.sign(n) * (digit >> shifted)) + initialMask;
      buckets[bucket].push(n);
    });

    let i = 0;
    buckets.forEach(bucket => bucket.forEach(n => {
      array[i] = n;
      i += 1;
    }));
    if ((max ^ mask) <= mask) break;
  }
}

const getArray = () => Array.from(
  { length: 1e6 },
  () => Math.floor(Math.random() * 0x80000000) * Math.sign(Math.random() - 0.5),
);

const isSorted = array => {
  for (let i = 1; i < array.length; i += 1) {
    if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}

const radixArray = getArray();
const nativeArray = radixArray.slice();

const radixStart = +new Date();
radixSort(radixArray);
const radixEnd = +new Date();

const nativeStart = +new Date();
nativeArray.sort();
const nativeEnd = +new Date();

document.write(`
  <dl>
    <dt>Sorted array in</dt>
    <dd>${radixEnd - radixStart}ms</dd>
  
    <dt>Properly sorted</dt>
    <dd>${isSorted(radixArray)}</dd>

    <dt>Sorted with Array.prototype.sort in</dt>
    <dd>${nativeEnd - nativeStart}ms</dd>
  </dl>
 `);
```

What's going on here?

We're sorting by base 8 (`0b1111` helps conceptualize the bitwise operations).

We create `0b1111 * 2 + 1` buckets, which is the number of items in the set `[-0b1111 … 0b1111]`

We use the "mask" to get each base 8 digit of a given number, e.g.

if `n = 0b101000101010`, `n & 0b1111` gives us `0b1010`, which is the first base 8 digit of `n`.

For each iteration, we get `n & 0b11110000`, then `n & 0b111100000000`, which isolates each successive base 8 digit.

For `n & 0b11110000`, we get `0b00100000`, from which we want `0b0010`, so we perform a right shift by 4 bits. The next iteration would be shifted by 8 bits, so on and so forth.

To account for negative values, we're basically performing two radix sorts simultaneously: the negative values are sorted in reverse, and the positive values are sorted in normal order. If the digit is negative, we say a digit of 7 should be at 0, 6 at 1, 5 at 2, etc.

If it is positive, we say a radix of 7 should be at index 14, 6 at 13, etc.

The check at the end - `(max ^ mask) <= mask` - determines if or not the mask has taken the most significant digit of the maximum value. If it has, the array is sorted.

Of course, radix sort only can work with integers.

If you need to use numbers larger than `0x80000000`, you could do an implementation with strings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure all these answers work, but I believe heavily in refactoring to explain what's going on under the hood. Thus, here is the answer with helper methods:

```
// helper
function getDigit(num, place) {
    return Math.floor(Math.abs(num) / Math.pow(10, place)) % 10;
}

// helper
function digitCount(num) {
    if (num === 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(num))) + 1;
}

// helper
function mostDigits(nums) {
    let max = 0;
    for (let num of nums) {
        max = Math.max(max, digitCount(num));
    }
    return max;
}

function radixSort(nums) {
    let maxDigits = mostDigits(nums);
    for (let k = 0; k < maxDigits; k++) {
        let buckets = Array.from({length: 10}, () => []);
        for (let num of nums) {
            let digit = getDigit(num, k);
            buckets[digit].push(num);
        }
        nums = [].concat(...buckets);
    }
    return nums;
}
```

Comment: Still using a lot of loops here (3) and thus this will not be a very efficient solution. Also this is a near exact copy of an answer I saw on another site, including names of methods and variables and their implementations. See here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/introduction-to-algorithms-with-javascript-examples/#radix-sort

Comment: With that said, I agree refactoring is good and to use "SOLID principles" like the "Single responsibility principle." Over all the answer is good enough, if it is yours. I will mention the article I linked is after you posted your answer, so they could have copied your answer and not the other way around.

Comment: It would be wise however to provide more insights into your answer itself. How you arrived at it? What are the main parts? Conceptual framework? All of which would help to elevate concerns of plagiarism too. As well as help people decide why they should select your answer vs the others.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered radix sort in CRLS 3rd edition section 8.3

The book provided the arcane origins of radix sort. It described the MSD version as antiquated and tricky. It also advised the implementation of the LSD.

Here I provide an implementation of radix sort using this technique.

Let's start by the pseudo-code:

[image: counting sort]

```
/**
 * @param k: the max of input, used to create a range for our buckets
 * @param exp: 1, 10, 100, 1000, ... used to calculate the nth digit
 */
Array.prototype.countingSort = function (k, exp) {
    /* eslint consistent-this:0 */
    /* self of course refers to this array */
    const self = this;

    /**
     * let's say the this[i] = 123, if exp is 100 returns 1, if exp 10 returns 2, if exp is 1 returns 3
     * @param i
     * @returns {*}
     */
    function index(i) {
        if (exp)
            return Math.floor(self[i] / exp) % 10;
        return i;
    }

    const LENGTH = this.length;

    /* create an array of zeroes */
    let C = Array.apply(null, new Array(k)).map(() => 0);
    let B = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < LENGTH; i++)
        C[index(i)]++;

    for (let i = 1; i < k; i++)
        C[i] += C[i - 1];

    for (let i = LENGTH - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        B[--C[index(i)]] = this[i];
    }

    B.forEach((e, i) => {
        self[i] = e
    });
}
```

And that's the  only tricky part, the rest is very simple

```
Array.prototype.radixSort = function () {
    const MAX = Math.max.apply(null, this);

    /* let's say the max is 1926, we should only use exponents 1, 10, 100, 1000 */
    for (let exp = 1; MAX / exp > 1; exp *= 10) {
        this.countingSort(10, exp);
    }
}
```

Now here is a how you can test this method

```
let a = [589, 111, 777, 65, 124, 852, 345, 888, 553, 654, 549, 448, 222, 165];
a.radixSort()
console.log(a);
```

Finally, as mentionned in the book, this particular algorithm works only because counting-sort is an in-place sorting algorithm, which means that if two elements tie, their order of occurence in the input array is preserved.

Comment: Concise and legible answer is +1 but you are using a lot of loops here (5) and thus this will not be a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

**My Implementation**

```js
// get the digits in the number by index
const getDigit = (num, index) => {
    return Math.floor(Math.abs(num) / Math.pow(10, index)) % 10;
}

// get the number of digits in a number
const getNumberOfDigits = (num) => {
    if(num === 0) return 1;

    return Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(num))) + 1; 
}

// get the max Number of digits in arr
const getMaxNumOfDigits = (arr) => {
    let max = 0;

    for(let item of arr) {
        max = Math.max(max, getNumberOfDigits(item))
    }

    return max;
}

// sorting the numbers
const radixSort = (arr) => {
    let maxIteration = getMaxNumOfDigits(arr),
        buckets;

    for (let i = 0; i < maxIteration; i++) {
        // set bucket to arr of 10 empty sub arrs
        buckets = Array.from({length: 10},  () => []);

        for(let item of arr) {
            // put the number in the right bucket position
            buckets[getDigit(item, i)].push(item);
        }
        
        // re-collect from the buckets
        arr = [].concat(...buckets);
    }

    return arr;
    }


radixSort([9, 212, 55, 19, 111, 3])


console.log(radixSort([9, 212, 55, 19, 111, 3]))
```

Comment: Concise and legible answer is +1 but you are using a lot of loops here (3) and thus this will not be a very efficient solution.

Answer (score 0):

User [Jason Leonhard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1783588/jasonleonhard) resurrected this old question to look for new solutions.  He seems to think that all the loops in the various answers are a performance problem.  While I doubt that's true, here's a version which at least hides the explicit loops behind array methods and a recursive call:

```js
// problems with Math.max for large parameter lists
const maximum = (ns) => ns .reduce ((m, n) => n > m ? n : m, -Infinity)

const radixSort = (ns, max = maximum (ns), divisor = 1) =>
  divisor < max
    ? radixSort (ns .reduce (
        (buckets, n) => ((buckets [(~~ (n / divisor)) % 10] .push (n)), buckets),
        [... Array (10)] .map (() => []) 
      ) .flat (), max , divisor * 10)
    : ns

console .log (radixSort ([5, 3, 88, 235, 65, 23, 4632, 234]))
console .log (radixSort ([589, 111, 777, 65, 124, 852, 345, 888, 553, 654, 549, 448, 222, 165]))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

This one only works with positive integers.  There are things we could do to optimize this a bit.  We could inline the call to `maximum`.  We could replace `[... Array (10)] .map (() => [])`  with `[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []]`.  Those would reduce clock time a tiny bit, but would not change the algorithmic complexity.

As with many other answers here, it looks like the algorithmic complexity is `O (n * d)` where `n` is the number of elements to sort, and `d` is the number of digits in the largest element.  The actual speed is probably less than that of the answer from Lior Elrom, since it exposes the same algorithm but uses recursive function calls instead of a while loop.  Or perhaps not, since it only finds the largest value once up front, instead of on every iteration like that answer.  But the important point is that without benchmarking, we really don't know which of these is the fastest, or for how many number / what highest number of digits any one of these is faster than another.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an LSD Radix Sorter implementation to sort integers and floating point numbers. It uses a bitmask to reduce the number of iterations.

Compared to Joseph Nields Answer is twice as fast when testing with an array of 1000000 numbers and a range of -0x80000000 to 0x80000000

https://github.com/aldo-gutierrez/bitmasksorterJS