# How to flat an array of arrays and order it in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, flat

Is there a better way to flat an array of arrays of integers? this solution is easy but I really don't know if it's time complexity is the best.

```js
const list = (arr) => {
//to avoid mutating the the entry data
   let newArr=[...arr]
return newArr.flat().sort((a,b)=>a-b)
}

// this logs [1,2,2,4,5,6,7,8]
console.log(
    list([2,[1,5],4,2,[6,8,7]])
)
```

I think maybe with reduce I can both flat the array and order it?

I'm trying to get a better performance at my algorithm

Comment: What tools are you using to measure the performance you're trying to improve?

Comment: `let newArr=[...arr]` is not required because [`flat(..)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) doesn't mutate the original array.

Comment: `const list = arr => arr.flat().sort();`

Answer (score 0):

There's not really a better way to flatten and sort integers; the only way to get better time complexity is to use a different sorting algorithm, since the default Javascript algorithm is merge sort, which has O(nlogn) complexity.  Here's [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_sorting#Practical_algorithms) for integer sorting algorithms that shouldn't be too difficult to implement.

I don't know what the range of your integers are, but if it's really small, you might want to just do counting sort (time complexity O(n)) since it's kind of easy to implement ([GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-sort/) has an implementation).  But, if you only have a few numbers that have a large range, you could do [radix sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36513414/javascript-radix-sort) (time complexity varies: could be as low as O(n) -- depends on parameters used).

Comment: well, actually I looked that before and Array.sort use the merge sort (as I found here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57763205/what-is-array-prototype-sort-time-complexity)

Comment: The JS specification leaves the `sort` technique up to the implementation.  v8 does one thing.  Firefox does another.  But unless you know a lot more about your data, you're not likely to code a faster implementation.  So really we're left with only, "There's not really a better way to flatten and sort integers."

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest.

```js
let abc = [[3,1],[4,1,5],[9,[2,6]]];
let abc1 = abc.flat(); // [3,1,4,1,5,9,[2,6]];
console.log(abc1.sort()); // [1,1,[2,6],3,4,5,9];
```

If you were looking for a way to make it so the base array no longer had any arrays inside, it should include a for loop for either the contents of the base array to find which ones are still array, or use map() to change just the contents of the detailed arrays. The top example of [flatMap() in this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) will show how to do both in one function!

Answer (score 0):

i'd use [flat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [sort](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort).  Sort needs a sorting function if you want to sort by numerical vs string value.

```
const arr = [2, [12,5], [4, 22,14], 1,[6,8,7]];
const flattened = arr.flat().sort((a,b) => a-b);
console.log(flattened);

// Array [1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 12, 14, 22]
```

Comment: why would use flatMap when there needs to be no conversion?

Comment: it flattens out the nested arrays.

Comment: I know what it does, it does the same thing as flat() here without all the extra overhead of the processing.

Comment: hmm. not sure what i did in my test case by it looks like flat could be used instead on flatmap. but i notice that sort needs a sort function or else it sorts by the string value.

Answer (score 0):

If built in methods you can do it with out making a copy of the array since flat already will spit out a new array.

```js
const flatSort = arr => arr.flat().sort();

console.log(flatSort([3,2,4,1,5,6,7,8,9, 0]));
console.log(flatSort([2,[1,5],4,2,[6,8,7]]));
```

You could code your own flatting and sort/insertion code. Many algorithms out there, here is a simple one to get ideas rolling in your head.

```js
function insertSort(arr, val) {
  const len = arr.length;
  let i = 0;
  while(i < arr.length) {
    if (arr[i] >= val) {
      arr.splice(i, 0, val);
      return;
    }
    i++;
  }
  arr.push(val);
}



const flatSort = (nestedArray, arr=[]) => {

  nestedArray.forEach(val => {
    if (Array.isArray(val)) {
      flatSort(val, arr);
    } else {
      insertSort(arr, val);
    }
  });

  return arr;
};


console.log(flatSort([3,2,4,1,5,6,7,8,9, 0]));

console.log(flatSort([2,[1,5],4,2,[6,8,7]]));
```